# Order by difference of days

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm doing a simple query, a select on a table with ID, name and date of birth. I would like to sort of low to high depending on the days that there difference between now and the date of birth of the table. Any ideas? I'm new to SQL and I can not think how.

Table User

```
SELECT * FROM User ORDER BY
```

Comment: Try using DATEDIFF. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Just order by date of birth. You'll get the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
select * from user order by datediff(d,dateofbirth, getdate())
```